# Update list view columns

Tags: c#, listview

I try the code below to update contents of row 1 of a listview but failed

```
listview.Items[0].SubItems[0].Text = "Column1";
listview.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text = "Column2";
listview.Items[0].SubItems[2].Text = "Column3";//failed here
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: "but failed". How are we supposed to know how it failed? Provide us with error details.

Comment: do you have 3 cols in the listview ? Does Faild==Crash?

Comment: check for null reference error..it might be causing problem...

Comment: listview.UpdateLayout() ?

Comment: btw shud it not be listView.Items[0].SubItems[0].Text = "Column1" following the same logic of urs..

Comment: the error is
InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'.

Comment: edited for the question according to user1974729, try it, still failed

Comment: what is the exception class?

Comment: how have u added the columnms?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to stet the value for a non-existent column, hence the exception. Make sure your list view definitely has 3+ columns.

Answer (score 0):

You must add SubItem first, then set its Text property.

```
listview.Items[0].SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem());
listview.Items[0].SubItems[2].Text = "Column3";
```

or

```
listview.Items[0].SubItems.Add("Column3");
```